# ABPersonHasImageData in Swift always returns false, no matter what I do

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I'm just getting into Swift and I'm stumbling over this one. I want to get the contact image of a contact in the method

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord!, property: ABPropertyID, identifier: ABMultiValueIdentifier)
```

I first check if the contact has an image and then copy that into a newly created constant with

```
if(ABPersonHasImageData(person))
    {
        let avatar : NSData = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail).takeRetainedValue()
    }
```

problem is, it always returns false in the simulator. Couldn't yet try it on my real phone.
What am I doing wrong? There are no errors. Extracting all other information from the contact works just fine.

Comment: Try it on real device. Seems to work fine for me on real device.

Comment: did a test with a new project, seems to be working there, even in the simulator. I'll go check my other code first ;)

Comment: Do not rely on the simulator as a dependable test bed. If you are getting unexpected/unanticipated results, run it on real hardware. This is the voice of painful experience talking.

Comment: thanks ;) but at the time it didn't even work on a real iPhone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, seems like there is no problem here after all. I just tried the code of my first post again and it works. On my device AND on the same simulator...

Since I first had this problem I reinstalled Xcode, maybe that solved it without me noticing. Weird bug...

Nonetheless: (non-)problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it myself just now. After trying it at work, I compared the code and noticed that I had left out one thing, which made it work:

This line:

```
pickerController.displayedProperties = [NSNumber(int: kABPersonPhoneProperty)]
```

I never thought of this as being the problem, since the image showed in the contacts view. Of course I now need to know how to include the UIImage of the contact in that list, but since it isn't available like `kABPersonPhoneProperty` I really don't know how to do this.

Is it maybe a bug? Shouldn't I be able to get the Image, even if the above line excludes everything but the phone numbers?

My workaround would be to implement

```
func peoplePickerNavigationController(peoplePicker: ABPeoplePickerNavigationController!, didSelectPerson person: ABRecord!) {
    //get the image, then hide everything except phone numbers
}
```

and then define what's hidden in the contacts view in the next step. But that wouldn't be very nice would it?

Maybe someone knows of a better solution. Many thanks!

Comment: does someone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason you always receive `false` from `ABPersonHasImageData` is your code doesn't have the permission to access any AddressBook data except for the data the user explicitly selected (phone number, in your case).

To request the permission, wrap your `presentViewController: ...` in `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` (or acquire the permission at some other point, but *before* you attempt to access the picture).

e.g.

```
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(nil) {
        (granted:Bool, err:CFError!) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            if granted {
                // TODO: present ABPeoplePickerNavigationController etc.
            }
        }
}
```